# Does $f$ measurable imply $f(x+k)$ measurable?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

my question is why $f$ measurable on $[0,\infty]$ implies $\{x: f(x+k)<a\}$
is measurable for each $k>0$ and each $a \in \mathbb R$.

I ask because in the proof that f measurable and differentiable implies f' is measurable, we write $f'= \lim n\to \infty \frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}$ and then since f(x) and $f(x+1/n)$ are measurable and the limit exists as f differentiable, then the limit is also differentiable.

But how do we see that f(x+1/n) is measurable? I tried to investiage the set 
$\{x: f(x+1/n)<a\}$ but I can't really undo the f as I don't know whether $f^{-1}(f(x+1/n))<f^{-1}(a)$ or not.Can I just split it into 2 cases and have two different sets, each measurable since f is, hence union of the two sets is measurable?$
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe we can use the fact that a translate of a measurable set is measurable? $$\{x:f(x+k)\lt a\}=\{x-k:f(x)\lt a\}$$

Comment: The function $x \mapsto x+k$ is continuous for any $k$.

Comment: Oh thanks, so the function g that takes x to x+k is continuous and so f(g(.)) is measurable since f is measurable and g continuous?

Comment: -bof,thanks for the reply, but  how to show that translates of that form are measurable? I know how to show for example if A measurable then A-k measurable, but here the conditions of the inclusion of each set is different, so its kind of confusing me whether we can use that fact without any further proof.